# "Issue with your SD Card" when copying files from Linux to memory card directly

Tags: file-system, file-transfer

Every time I copy some music and photos from my Linux computer to my phone, my phone says the SD card is corrupted.

Here's more details:

1. I formatted SD card from my phone.
2. Ejected the SD card from phone.
3. Connected the card to PC running Linux with a card reader.
4. Copied files to the SD card's `Music/` and `Pictures/backgrounds/` directories with Nemo file manger (didn't delete anything that's put by the Android formatter).
5. Ejected SD card from PC.
6. Inserted SD card in phone.
7. Phone says to format the SD card with message: "Issue with Sandisk SD card" "Tap to fix".
8. Inserted the SD card again to PC and everything looks good on PC, no files seem to be corrupted.
9. To eliminate the possibility of a software-related issue, I performed a restart of the phone and started all over again from `1`.

If I format SD card, everyone knows what happens, and then I repeat step 2 to 6 and it still continues to show same message. What could be the issue here?

This doesn't happen with data cable transfer or SSH transfer. But what's going wrong with SD card?

I see the files have owner of the PC, the files are readable by the default user, and no other attributes are set with `chattr` for example.

EDIT

1. This time I copied 5 music, and it's still corrupted.
2. Looks like copying or creating any file makes in incompatible.

EDIT 2
TL;DR: Issue fixed somehow

I was able to reproduce this issue multiple times, persisted across reboots, but somehow I was able to create an empty file which didn't corrupt the SD card, then I was able to copy all the Music, it worked as usual. I am not sure what happened there.

Comment: it's a windows file system, needs fsck_msdos all the time :)

Comment: This ^^^ and you should avoid that procedure. Keep the SD card in the phone and use USB to transfer the files.